# How do I subscribe to events? I'm getting this error: Cannot read property 'currentProvider' of undefined

Tags: node.js, events, ethereum, smartcontracts, web3js

I'm getting the following error message when trying to subscribe to Events on a private Ethereum blockchain:

> Cannot read property 'currentProvider' of undefined

**Setup of Web3:**

```
const Web3 = require("web3");
this.web3 = new Web3(Web3.givenProvider || "ws://localhost:8545");
```

Works:

```
this.factoryContract.getPastEvents(
  "allEvents",
  {
    fromBlock: 0,
    toBlock: "latest"
  },
  (err, events) => {
    console.log(events);
  }
);
```

Throws error:

```
this.factoryContract.events
  .allEvents(
    {
      fromBlock: 0
    },
    (error, event) => {
      console.log(event);
    }
  )
  .on("data", event => {
    console.log(event);
  });

  this.factoryContract.events
  .TaskCreated(
    {
      fromBlock: 0
    },
    (error, event) => {
      console.log(event);
    }
  );
```

Any ideas how to fix that / what the error is?

Node version: 10.14.2
Web3: 1.0.0

Comment: What are you using to run your private Ethereum blockchain?

Comment: @foba ganache. Already tried chaning the setup of web 3 to make sure ganache is used as a websocket provider but still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is an issue of the current web3 1.0.0.51 release and is supposed to be fixed in the next release.
https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/releases